# Combine rows based on multiple criteria and then sum one column

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Group rows together when columns A,B,C,D,F match (D can be blank and still be considered a match) and then sum the "Qty" column.

I can `FILTER` and I can `SUM`, but I can't seem to do both.

This formula will be in ['estimate-Tally'!A2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8tjT4cmuC7jG7o9aC0LTO_labvpr6ptUp_3g6p5VB8/edit#gid=1185069406&range=A2)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:X6, 
 "select A,B,C,' ','  ',F,sum(G),H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,B,C,' ','  ',F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X", 0),
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]